# String to int array

Tags: c, arrays, string, int

I've worked on this for awhile but I keep getting either {0,0,0,0,0}, or {2751685, 2751685, etc} or {57,58,59,60,etc}

```
  void getGuess(int guess[], int length) {
        char thisGuess[length]; 
        int i=0;
        printf("Enter your guess.\n");
        scanf("%s", &thisGuess);

        for(i=0; i<length; i++) {
            printf("the guess = %d\n",(int)thisGuess[i]) ;
            guess[i] = (int)(thisGuess)-48;

            printf("%d  ", guess[i]);
        }
  }
```

I want to enter a string, 12345,  and get it so

```
 guess[0] = 1
 guess[1] = 2
 guess[2] = 3 
 etc
```

suggestions on my code?

Comment: I suspect `48` is used to convert from the digit `0` to the integer value `0`. If that is correct: **Don't** use magic numbers! You obfuscate your code. Just use the _character integer constant_ `'0'`.

Comment: Use the actual length of the string you got with scanf in your for loop, not your length parameter...

Comment: `(int)(thisGuess) - 48` should be `thisGuess[i] - 48`  (or preferably `'0'` rather than `48`). Also you should stop looping at the end of the input that just happened (not `length`) and you need some way to prevent buffer overflow if they type more than `length`.

Answer (score 0):

The length of an char array usually isn't equal to the length of the C-style string it contains.

```
void getGuess(int guess[], int length) {
    char thisGuess[length]; 
    size_t i = 0;
    printf("Enter your guess.\n");
    scanf("%s", thisGuess); // a char *, rather than a char (*)[length] is expected
    size_t guessLength = strlen(thisGuess);
    for(i = 0; i < guessLength; i++) {
        printf("the guess = %d\n", thisGuess[i]);
        guess[i] = thisGuess - '0';
        printf("%d  ", guess[i]);
    }
}
```

Alternatively, add

```
if(!isdigit(thisGuess[i]))
    continue;
```

to avoid potential out-of-bound access.